# Do god mode console command affect companions?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

If i'm with a companion and use TGM for god mode, does he/she will be invicible too, or no? Is there a way to make my companions invicible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they won't be invicinble with god mode. What you can do is click on them as to start a conversation and use `forceav health 9999999` to increase their health. This should probably give you an invincible effect.

You can also make companions essential through the console command `setessential base_id 1`. Switch base_id with the code you can find in the wiki pages (eg. Boone's base id is **00092bd2**)

Answer (score 1):

Companions can't die in normal mode; they only get knocked unconscious.  They will only die on hardcore, but why would you be using hardcore mode and turn on god mode?  Just turn off the hardcore mode.